# Stopwatch resistant against system time changes

Tags: java, date, time, stopwatch

I want to make a stopwatch in Java, which is immune against system time changes.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();

// System time changes

long stop = System.nanoTime();

long elapsed = start - stop;
```

So the problem with this code is that when the system time is changing, then the time measurement is wrong.

Comment: It shouldn't. The source used by `System.nanoTime()` is a counter which is _not_ sensible to system time changes. Anyway --> Guava has `Stopwatch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above code should be resistant against system time changes according to the API:

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not
>   related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time.